# .write() en una sola linea Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsear

Soy bastante nuevo en el mundo de la programación y en el mundo de Python (tengo una base de principiante y los conceptos básicos adquiridos), en este caso estoy intentando hacer un script el cual yo le ingreso un archivo de texto separado por "|" y mi script modifique ciertos campos (detallados en el código) y una vez que se modifican se escriban en otro archivo de txt el cual genero en mi programa.

```
import time
import random
entrada = input ("Ingresa CDR a modificar: ")
fecha_cdr = str(time.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
fecha = str(time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
numero = str(random.randrange(1000000, 10000000))
archivo = open(entrada ,'r+')
contenido = archivo.read()
#genero una lista separando por |

contenido = contenido.split("|")

def funcion_1():
    #modifico los valores que quiero
    contenido [7] = "valor7"
    contenido [35] = "valor35"
 #genero una copia

    resultado = contenido
       #paso la lista a str separado por |    
    resultado = "|".join(resultado)
     #genero un archivo txt donde escribo el resultado
    final = open("que.txt","w")
    final.write(str('resultado: "' + resultado + 'directorio al que se manda el archivo en otro proceso' + fecha + "numero" + numero ))
    archivo.close()

def funcion_2():
    contenido [4] = "valor4"
    contenido [38] = "valor38"
    final = open("fin.txt","w")
    final.write(str('resultado: "' + resultado + 'directorio al que se manda el archivo en otro proceso' + fecha + "numero" + numero ))
    archivo.close()

def funcion_3():
    contenido [72] = "valor72"
    contenido [87] = "valor87"
    final = open("fin.txt","w")
    final.write(str('resultado: "' + resultado + 'directorio al que se manda el archivo en otro proceso' + fecha + "numero" + numero ))
    archivo.close()





if "soy1" in entrada:
    funcion_1()
elif "soy2" in entrada:
    funcion_2()
elif "soy3" in entrada:
    funcion_3()
```

El problema que estoy teniendo es que todo lo que se escribe luego de la variable "resultado", queda en otra linea de texto (como si tuviese un "\n", cuando no lo tiene).Todavía no pude determinar si es un problema de la longitud de algunos archivos que este causando esto o si el join() puede influir en algo. En fin lo que me gustaría saber es como es posible hacer quedar todo mi texto en una sola linea y no tener un salto de linea.

Desde ya muchas gracias.
Saludos,

Comment: Lo más probable es que el archivo de entrada termina con un salto de línea. Por lo general, archivos de texto terminan así. Por que piensas que no lo tiene?

Comment: Por la informacion que tengo, el texto que recibo, tiene una sola linea (extensa).Por ende no creo que ese sea la problematica, igualmente en caso de que asi sea, como se podria resolver?

Comment: Una posibilidad: `contenido = archivo.read().strip('\n')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente, archivos de texto terminan con un salto de línea (`\n`), así que es muy probable que la cadena devuelto por `read` termina con tal carácter. Después de `split`, el salto de línea se encuentra en el último miembro de `contenido` y asimismo después de `join`, estará al final de `resultado`.

Podría eliminarlo en el momento de leer:

```
contenido = archivo.read().strip('\n').split('|')
```

Comment: Buena respuesta. Te faltó una comilla en el \n :P

Comment: @borjinha10: gracias